How to Move Pose and Skeleton to Fix GLTF Model Import Issues
I imported a GLTF model, and the settings in the app I exported it from are causing the bubbles to be added incorrectly due to an issue with Blender and the enabled setting. I need to move the Pose and SK_Demon_Skeleton to SK_Demon so I can delete the erroneous bubbles. I was hoping drag and drop would work, but it didn’t. How can I move these two to delete the bubbles and fix the model?
The name of the model was SK_Demon, so somehow it got confused and thought that SK_Demon was supposed to be the skeleton, not the name.


The bubbles are just visualization of the bones. You can enable/disable them from the viewport overlays dropdown at the upper right of the viewport, or you can change their display to something else in the Armature settings panel.
Note that depending on your import settings, other ways of visualizing the bones may not look like you expect, even though they are 'correct', as described in the "Bone Direction" section in the addon documentation:

Bone direction: Changes the heuristic the importer uses to decide where to place bone tips. Note that the Fortune setting may cause inaccuracies in models that use non-uniform scaling. Otherwise this is purely aesthetic. The default value will not change axis, and is best for re-exporting from Blender. This default option will change display mode (adding shape and changing relationship line) to have a better view, even if original bones axis are not the most accurate.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#properties

I was about to comment that the bubbles are still there when I export. But thinking about it I'm not sure if I actually tried exporting. I will try to export to make sure they are not there and I will try this setting to see if it helps.

Although I did figure out that the problem was an export setting Export Vertex Skin Weights: If your mesh has complex skinning, Blender might struggle with it. The problem is I have to combine this model with other animations in separate files to make it all one model so I can use them in an engine that requires all the animations to be in the same file. The problem is the program I'm exporting from wont let me turn this off for the separate animation files. Not sure why. I will play around with this setting when I get a chance.

I unchecked the Bones option in the viewport overlays as you said and they did all go away. I'm pretty new to Blender this isnt going to do anything crazy like make it act like there arent any bones making the animations not work?

The animations only seem to work if this is checked. I have the same problem with FBX. I'll investigate the export options in Unreal to see if I can get this resolved.

I did not get this resolved yet.
